# Firebase performance is not displaying/listing some endpoints used in the android app

Tags: android, firebase-performance

I'm using firebase performance monitoring in my android app. For the most part, it works great!

Different endpoints are listed in their own rows but the uncategorised row has a lot of samples (more than a million), why is that?

Also, some endpoints which are called a lot are not shown as different rows? What could be the issue here? Has anyone faced something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase performance monitoring now supports adding custom url patterns. So if some endpoints are not being captured, you can now create an exact custom url for that endpoint or patterns.

From the docs:

> Firebase attempts to match request URLs to any configured custom URL
>   patterns before falling back to automatic URL pattern matching. For
>   any matching requests to a custom URL pattern, Firebase aggregates the
>   requests' data under the custom URL pattern.

More mentioned in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/https_traces?authuser=0#custom-url-patterns).